# How to add uibutton,uiimage as a subview on mpmovieplayercontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need some suggestion for how to add `uibutton` and `uiimage` on `mpmovieplayercontroller` like vine app.

I try to this concept using `mpmovieplayercontroller` but the `uibutton` and `uiimage` are not displayed. Only video played on this player.

```
  CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        // code for 4-inch screen
        [logotitleimg setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 85, 160, 50)];
        twitterloginbtn.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 330, 280, 45);
        fbloginbtn.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 390, 280, 45);
        signupbtn.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 450, 280, 45);
        //signinlbl.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 510, 200, 21);
        loginbtn.frame =  CGRectMake(220, 510, 295, 25);

    }
    else
    {
        // code for 3.5-inch screen
        [logotitleimg setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 85, 160, 50)];
        twitterloginbtn.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 240, 280, 45);
        fbloginbtn.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 300, 280, 45);
        signupbtn.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 360, 280, 45);
        //signinlbl.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 430, 200, 21);
        loginbtn.frame =  CGRectMake(220, 428, 295, 25);
    }

    NSURL *contentURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"spll" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    mc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:contentURL];
    mc.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    mc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    mc.contentURL = contentURL;
    [mc prepareToPlay];
    mc.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    mc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [mc setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];
    [mc play];
    [self.view addSubview:mc.view];

    /*overlayview=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mc.view.bounds];
    [mc.view addSubview:overlayview];*/

    logotitleimg=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [logotitleimg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nativelogo.png"]];
    [mc.view addSubview:logotitleimg];    //[overlayview addSubview:logotitleimg];

    twitterloginbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [twitterloginbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [twitterloginbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter_signin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [twitterloginbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(twitterloginaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mc.view addSubview:twitterloginbtn];

    fbloginbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [fbloginbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [fbloginbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_login native.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fbloginbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(fbcalling:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mc.view addSubview:fbloginbtn];

    signupbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [signupbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [signupbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"email_signup.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [signupbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(signuppage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mc.view addSubview:signupbtn];

    loginbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [loginbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [loginbtn setTitle:@"Already have an acount? Sign in now." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginbtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:10]];
    [loginbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(loginpage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mc.view addSubview:loginbtn];
```

Comment: `[mc addSubView:anyView];`

Comment: Mutawe I follow u=your  above format but I got this error No visible @interface for 'MPMoviePlayerController' declares the selector'addSubview:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] intWithFrame...];

UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
[mc.view addSubView:btn];
[mc.view addSubView:img];
```